# How it works with modified go-ethereum source code

Tags: go-ethereum, golang

I modified go-ethereum source code and built it. I am wondering if I want to test and run geth with the modified source code in mainnet or testnet, and how it works in the mainnet or testnet.

1. How to test the modified source in mainnet or testnet
2. How it works with modified source in mainnet or testnet

Comment: This question is very wide, it would depends on the lines of code you modified and if those affect to the way geth interacts with mainnet/testnet or not. For instance, you could have modified geth to write down in a file log traces about sync status and that would not affect the correctness of your local node. In flipside, if you modify the validation algorithm it might be a completely different escenario

Comment: Depending on your modifications it might just work. If the changes are compatible with the network you will have no problem, if they aren't compatible then after some time your node will be kicked by the other nodes.

Comment: I am still confused with modification in my side and it will be affected to the nodes in mainnet/testnet. Which source modification is acceptable or not. Could you explain it in detail how it affects in existing network? What do you mean by depending on modifications which is compatible or not? Thanks.

Comment: What does "it" refer to in the title and question 2? Geth?

Comment: It refers to the geth in mainnet/testnet.